# How to save a new record

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I am working on an existing project which was passed on to me. It uses EF5.  I created a new table in the database, and am trying to add a row to this table. I am used to making use of DBContext, but in this case, the existing code seems to use ObjectContext.

I have tried to create a new row in the DB, but this does not work:

```
using (var context = new MyDatabaseEntities())
                {
                    var paymentLog = context.PaymentLog.CreateObject();
                    paymentLog.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                    paymentLog.ErrorCode = errorCode.ToString();
                    paymentLog.ErrorMessage = message;
                    paymentLog.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
```

Like that, there are naturally no changes to the database.  When I add the following line `context.PaymentLog.AddObject(paymentLog);` I get an error saying "The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null".

Also, when I try attaching the entity similar to how DBContext works, I get a similar error too.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** I have also tried the following:

```
context.PaymentLog.Attach(paymentLog);
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(paymentLog, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This produces this error: "An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add after the values has been set on the paymentLog object:

```
context.PaymentLog.Add(paymentLog);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: When using the attach command, I get the following error: "An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context"

Comment: Check Mike McCaughans answer and combine with mine.. you should let the Entity Framework handle the primary keys

Comment: I am a bit tired, I changed my answer a bit now.. add the Guid again and then change the attach and other bits

Comment: THe 'Add' method does not seem to exist. I have used 'AddObject' instead, but have the same exact problem.

Comment: I am at a loss here.. what version of VS, MVC, EF and .NET are you using? It sounds to me like some kind of bug or older version of the EF.

Comment: Also, did you create the controller from scratch? It might be easier to scaffold it from the model(just rightclick the proper model class and choose scaffold). This is a good way to start learning to understand controllers and EF. Study the controller and and behavior. By scaffolding you can get the Create-method created by EF and it is created by the standards for the version you are using.

Comment: Just remember to save your controller code elsewhere before removing the controller and scaffolding it.

Comment: It's EF5 and VS 2015

Comment: Hmm, Could you try using "entities.AttachTo("PaymentLog", paymentLog);"

Answer (score 0):

The error is kind of already telling you what's up:

> The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null

The "EntityKey property" refers to the property which represents the key of your table. In your case, it's likely the `Guid` property. Note that in your code, you are setting that property before adding/attaching the entity. Usually, the key would be generated by your data store, and you wouldn't supply the value yourself.

I think if you remove the following line:

```
paymentLog.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

And try adding/attaching, it should work.

Comment: I did as you said, but am getting the following error on Attach now: "An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context." (the same error)

Comment: What about with `AddObject`?

Comment: Tried that too, and combined with the answer above. No luck

Comment: I'd do a web search with the text of that error message and see what else comes up. That's about all the advice I can give you at this point.